# How to Create the right array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using API Random.ORG with vendor engine LoLFactor\RandomORG\

My Code:

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
use LoLFactor\RandomORG\RandomORGClient;
$client = new RandomORGClient('5035-35353-53535-53535-3535');

$data = $client->generateSignedIntegers(1, 1, 60);
$i = 0;
$arr = array();
foreach($data as $randomInt) {
    array_push($arr, ($randomInt));
}
echo '<br>';
var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

And i get array

```
"["2.0",{"random":{"method":"generateSignedIntegers","hashedApiKey":"FZSXJR+2P+umSj1UIOvBEc3RpYuwh8ZQfqppk8O5froIsgTlcPWRmoYkKzLB07cCs4TXgMcZS+MduDyF0RK9+Q==","n":1,"min":1,"max":60,"replacement":true,"base":10,"data":[48],"completionTime":"2015-10-03 11:52:32Z","serialNumber":276},"signature":"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","bitsUsed":6,"bitsLeft":248458,"requestsLeft":742,"advisoryDelay":0},"G5nucL0Wdy9xtbejw"]"
```

Its bad browser console:
[image]

But i need array this type:

```
"{"random":{"method":"generateSignedIntegers","hashedApiKey":"FZSXJR+2P+umSj1UIOvBEc3RpYuwh8ZQfqppk8O5froIsgTlcPWRmoYkKzLB07cCs4TXgMcZS+MduDyF0RK9+Q==","n":1,"min":1,"max":60,"replacement":true,"base":10,"data":[48],"completionTime":"2015-10-03 11:52:32Z","serialNumber":276},"signature":"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","bitsUsed":6,"bitsLeft":248458,"requestsLeft":742,"advisoryDelay":0}"
```

Its good browser console:
[image]
without code `["2.0",` and code `,"G5nucL0Wdy9xtbejw"]` at end.

How i can delete first and last key-values. ?
I try array_merge , array_split but do not understand. How to create array that i need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like instead of `var_dump(json_encode($arr));` you just want `var_dump(json_encode($arr[1]));` ... as in, add the `[1]` to get the middle element of the array.

Alternatively, `$arr = $arr[1];`

But, `array_slice`, `array_pop`, `array_shift` won't really help you. They'll shorten the array to a single element, but you don't want the outer array at all, so just extract the middle element that you do want.